# jQuery toogle - one of open, others hide - wherever in the code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two problems with it.
1. When I click the first 'Details', the text opens below, but I would like if I open the second 'Details', the first to be closed.
2. It is also important that the 'Details' will be applied earlier in the code. There will be some queues between class="clickme" and id="#me"
In this case the code is not working.

```
<p class="clickme" style="cursor:pointer;">Details</p>
<div id="me" style="display: none; background-color: yellow;">
Here is the text, which appears for clicking above.
</div>

<p class="clickme" style="cursor:pointer;">Details</p>
<div>hello</div>
<div id="me" style="display: none; background-color: blue;">
Here is the text, which appears for clicking above.
</div>

         $('.clickme').click(function() {
              //.next take the next DOM element
              $(this).next('#me:first').animate({
                   height: 'toggle'
                   }, 200
              );
         });
```

Can you help me, pls?

Best Regards,
Atti

```
                <div id="cs_containter">
                    <div id="cs_left">
                        <div id="cs_left_image">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="cs_right">
                        <div id="cs_right_main">
                            <div id="cs_right_main_title">
                                <h1 class="cs_aj_cim">Something New</p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="cs_right_main_content">
                                <p class="cs_short_description">
                                Minimum text is...
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="cs_right_main_bottom">
                                <div id="cs_right_main_bottom_left">
                                    <div id="csrmbr_ker">
                                        <p class="cs_reszletek_ar">Like</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="csomag_right_main_bottom_right">
                                    <div id="csrmbr_keret">
                                        <p class="clickme csomag_reszletek_ar" style="cursor:pointer;">It cannot be working...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="clear"></div>
                </div>
                    <div class="me" style="display: none; background-color: yellow;">
                        Text which is yellow
                    </div>

                        <div id="cs_containter">
                    <div id="cs_left">
                        <div id="cs_left_image">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="cs_right">
                        <div id="cs_right_main">
                            <div id="cs_right_main_title">
                                <h1 class="cs_aj_cim">Something New</p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="cs_right_main_content">
                                <p class="cs_short_description">
                                Minimum text is...
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="cs_right_main_bottom">
                                <div id="cs_right_main_bottom_left">
                                    <div id="csrmbr_ker">
                                        <p class="cs_reszletek_ar">Like</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="csomag_right_main_bottom_right">
                                    <div id="csrmbr_keret">
                                        <p class="clickme csomag_reszletek_ar" style="cursor:pointer;">It cannot be working...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="clear"></div>
                </div>
                    <div class="me" style="display: none; background-color: yellow;">
                        Text which is yellow
                    </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $mes = $('.me')
$('.clickme').click(function () {
    //.next take the next DOM element
    var $me = $(this).nextAll('.me:first').animate({
        height: 'toggle'
    }, 200);
    $mes.not($me).hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/axea78fc/3/

Comment: need to share the code in the question.. not just a link

Comment: I don't understand something. You can see the code above. When I applied the solution the original code, it is not working. Do you have any idea why it can be like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since you have multiple elements use class instead of id for `me` elements. ID of an element must be unique

```
var $mes = $('.me')
$('.clickme').click(function () {
    //.next take the next DOM element
    var $me = $(this).nextAll('.me:first').animate({
        height: 'toggle'
    }, 200);
    $mes.not($me).hide();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zz36rnco/)

Comment: I don't understand something. You can see the code above. When I applied the solution the original code, it is not working. Do you have any idea why it can be like this?

Comment: @Atti http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zz36rnco/2/ - also `cs_containter` should be a class as it is repeated

Comment: I change id for class... I can see in Fiddle, that the code is working, but when it is implemented to the original environment the hidden div does not appear at all. I click but nothing happens. Really magic...

Comment: when I leave only <p> in the original code, then it is ok, but if I move up one level to div, the failure comes... the Details is not open down. What can be the problem?

Comment: @Atti the code is depended on the structure... so you need to define the structure of the code first

Comment: what do you mean under the structure of the code? In my opinion this is the structure, what I shared with you. Could you give me some idea?
I think so that it should work on if it is worked independently... really magic

Comment: @Atti can you share the html where it is not wirking

Comment: I try to analyze the code. The result is if I move the <p> tag out of the code (eg. the beginning of the code), which includes the clickme class, than it is working. 
I think there are some problems with the structures of divs.
What do you think of it?

Comment: First, Thanks your lot of help...
I create JSFiddle...
I hope this will be enough to analyze...
https://jsfiddle.net/5gs93wy6/

Comment: I think I know what is the problem... There are further divs up to top and among these divs there are some id="" attributum.
I create a new fiddle.

Comment: Dear Arun! There was a mistake in my code. Perfectly working by you. Now it was a very big help for meg. Thanks, Thanks! :)